# Preventing FATAL_ERROR on FetchContent_Declare

Tags: cmake

In many places, CMake use `message(FATAL_ERROR "...")` to signal unrecoverable errors. Now, this error is not always unrecoverable and I am not a ware a try/catch mechanism to work around that.

Example:
find_package, if it fails (package_FOUND is not set) do
a FetchContent_Declare/FetchContent_MakeAvailable using a git url, if it fails do
a add_subdirectory.

Here, if find_package + REQUIRED is used and the package does not find either the library or one of the required components it throws a hard error. This is a bit too much but we can workaround the issue using only OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS and then check if our required targets are satisfied (if(TARGET <..>)).

If we give multiple URLs to FetchContent it can manage fallback. But if you give a mix of path to disk and URL it says:
`At least one entry of URL is a path (invalid in a list)` and errors out.

How to we prevent FetchContent from throwing hard error that are actually recoverable.